# [Tizen][Bluetooth]Gear device is not turning on bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, tizen-web-app

I was trying the Bluetooth web application for tizen on gear device.

When I try to check the code 
**tizen.systeminfo.getCapability(BLUETOOTH_FEATURE_KEY);
It returns false.** However, the device has bluetooth capability.
It also gets connected to other device as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use appropriate feature key and add required privileges.

```
try
     {
       /* Checks if a device supports bluetooth API */
       var bluetooth = tizen.systeminfo.getCapability("http://tizen.org/feature/network.bluetooth");
       console.log(" Bluetooth = " + bluetooth);
       document.getElementById("isOnBL").innerHTML = "Bluetooth : "+bluetooth;
     }
     catch (error)
     {
        console.log("Error name: " + error.name + ", message: " + error.message);
     }
```

Add privilege

```
   <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/system"/>
```